# TF31001: Cannot Connect to Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

This error occurs after restoring database on TFS
[image]

Please guide if anyone resolve this error. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can't just restore a TFS database and expect the it to work. Did you follow the DR documentation for TFS that explains how to properly restore it? Update your question to state **exactly** what happened, what databases were restored, how were they restored, and what actions you took on your application tier server before and after the restore.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly please make sure you have correctly restored the database, see [Back up and restore TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/back-up-restore-tfs), then check it again.

If the issue still exists, just try to check below things to narrow down the issue:

- Make sure the SQL Server is stated and available, and the network
  connectivity is OK.
- Check the Service Account, make sure the Service Account has been
  added in SQL Server.
- Trying refer to the **solution** in below link to fix the issue:
  http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/04/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/

If above solution can not resolve the problem, please check the Event log. The Windows Event Log is a good candidate where to look for the potential cause.